# Histogram starting from 0 after setting the set argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram for my integer variable which has a very inconsistent values, here is the output of summary function applied to the variable:

> Min:347  1st Qu:8786  Median:20886    Mean:69522 3rd Qu:50400 Max:4069360

So as you can see it ranges from 300 to 4,000,000

Here is the code I am using to create the histogram:

```
 ggplot(data=mydata, aes(mydata$variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..), 
                 breaks=seq(300, 2000000, by = 20000), 
                 col="#00AFBB", 
                 fill="#00AFBB", 
                 alpha=.2) + 
  geom_density(col=2) +
```

Although I sat the seq argument and using different values, the histogram keep starting from 0 and ending with 4000000 as follows:

[image]

What can I do to adjust the histogram so it seems more balanced and plot the values correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "more balanced" and plotting the values "correctly"? The plot displays your values *as they are*.

Comment: There are only 7 or 8 values above 1000000 so most of them are actually less than 1000000 and what I am trying to do is to change the scale of x axis so not to start with 0 and end with 4 millions but instead starting from about 1000 to 1000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either place a restriction on the values mapped to the x-axis, effectively filtering them out:

```
+ scale_x_continouous(limits=c(0, 1000000))
```

or zoom in on the relevant part of your plot:

```
+ coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 1000000))
```

Do note that your first line can be reduced to:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(variable)) +
```

as `data` *is* the first argument to ggplot, and the variables referenced in `aes` are always searched for in the data.frame (given to the `data` argument).

Comment: Thank you very much that what I was looking for. And for your note also thank you I used to write the way you mentioned though.